# Motion - grey screen with camera module

Tags: camera, raspicam, motion

I set up motion and the UV4L drivers for the raspberry pi camera module, but when I try to start motion with `sudo motion`, and connect with VLC I only get a grey screen.
This is what the terminal says:

```
[0] Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0] Motion 3.2.12 Started
[0] ffmpeg LIBAVCODEC_BUILD 3482368 LIBAVFORMAT_BUILD 3478785
[0] Thread 1 is from /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0] motion-httpd/3.2.12 running, accepting connections
[0] motion-httpd: waiting for data on port TCP 8080
[1] Thread 1 started
[1] cap.driver: "raspicam"
[1] cap.card: "Camera Board OV5647"
[1] cap.bus_info: "CSI"
[1] cap.capabilities=0x01000001
[1] - VIDEO_CAPTURE
[1] - READWRITE
[1] Test palette YU12 (320x240)
[1] Using palette YU12 (320x240) bytesperlines 480 sizeimage 115200 colorspace 00000000
[1] found control 0x00980900, "brightness", range 0,100 
[1]     "brightness", default 50, current 50
[1] found control 0x00980901, "contrast", range -100,100 
[1]     "contrast", default 0, current 0
[1] found control 0x00980902, "saturation", range -100,100 
[1]     "saturation", default 0, current 0
[1] found control 0x0098090e, "red balance", range 0,800 
[1]     "red balance", default 100, current 100
[1] found control 0x0098090f, "blue balance", range 0,800 
[1]     "blue balance", default 100, current 100
[1] found control 0x08000000, "shutter speed", range 0,65535 
[1]     "shutter speed", default 0, current 0
[1] found control 0x08000001, "zoom factor", range 1,8 
[1]     "zoom factor", default 0, current 1
[1] ioctl (VIDIOCGCAP): Invalid argument
[1] Could not fetch initial image from camera
[1] Motion continues using width and height from config file(s)
[1] Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1] Started stream webcam server in port 8081
[1] Retrying until successful connection with camera
[1] cap.driver: "raspicam"
[1] cap.card: "Camera Board OV5647"
[1] cap.bus_info: "CSI"
[1] cap.capabilities=0x01000001
[1] - VIDEO_CAPTURE
[1] - READWRITE
[1] Test palette YU12 (320x240)
[1] Using palette YU12 (320x240) bytesperlines 480 sizeimage 115200 colorspace 00000000
[1] found control 0x00980900, "brightness", range 0,100 
[1]     "brightness", default 50, current 50
[1] found control 0x00980901, "contrast", range -100,100 
[1]     "contrast", default 0, current 0
[1] found control 0x00980902, "saturation", range -100,100 
[1]     "saturation", default 0, current 0
[1] found control 0x0098090e, "red balance", range 0,800 
[1]     "red balance", default 100, current 100
[1] found control 0x0098090f, "blue balance", range 0,800 
[1]     "blue balance", default 100, current 100
[1] found control 0x08000000, "shutter speed", range 0,65535 
[1]     "shutter speed", default 0, current 0
[1] found control 0x08000001, "zoom factor", range 1,8 
[1]     "zoom factor", default 0, current 1
[1] ioctl (VIDIOCGCAP): Invalid argument
```

What is the problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following 2 lines to `/etc/init.d/motion` after the `#` lines

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
export LD_PRELOAD
```

Comment: You might want to consider including some explanation as to why this would solve the OP's issue - just to improve your answer quality.

Comment: I will try that, thanks. I suppose this just loads the v4l library for arm, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a 2B and found the above answer didn't work.  What did work for me was adding the line `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` within `/etc/init.d/motion` just before the daemon is started.

Pi is running 4.1.10-v7+ #821.  What I have found odd though is that in trying to do the same thing with an original B+ it refuses to work just kills daemon when motion is detected.  NB this B+ updates only to 4.1.7+ #817 and error message is:-

motion: [1] Closing video device `/dev/video0`

kernel: [   57.116367] CPU: 0 PID: 2842 Comm: motion Not tainted 4.1.7+ #817

Other than the kernel the setup is the same as the 2B.